# pd.set_option doesn't change what dataframe shows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

[Here what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2XUC.png) In setting the parameters of the dataframe (max rows, max columns) there is a problem. After run, the dataframe hides part of the rows and columns. This is the code:

```
   import pandas as pd
   pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
   pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
   import pandas_datareader.data as web
   import datetime as dt

   start = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
   end = dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1)

   df = web.DataReader('Race', 'yahoo', start, end)

   df.reset_index(inplace=True)


   print(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways:

**Try this as you are already trying.**

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

**Or try this:**

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
```

**or maybe this:**

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 5, 'display.max_columns', None): 
    display(my_df)
```

Comment: You are using `print(df)` to check the dataframe but this will only work when you use `df.head()` if you use `print(df)` then it will not work.

Comment: How are you printing your data? like `print(df)`or `df.head()`

Comment: I noticed that if i delete print(df) and run the code, the dataframe is printed anyway

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code and got all 250 rows and 7 columns - `'Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'`.
I changed this

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

to

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
```

And added one more option

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
```

Result:
I get 250 rows and 7 columns

[image]
[image]

Instead of setting the values to 500, you can set them to `None` if you dont want to predefine them

When I remove the 2 `pd.set_option` statements, I got the data displayed with first 5 rows, followed by 3 dots and the last 5 rows with first 3 columns followed by 3 dots and then last 3 columns. So the `pd.set_option` changes the way the output is displayed.

Comment: I added an image of the result. But I would like to see all the rows and all the columns and not a grouping.

Comment: @GabrieleNicodemi I am not sure if it has to do with different pandas versions. What version of pandas and python are you using? I am running on python 3.8 with pandas 1.0.4.

Comment: i'm running Python 3.8 with Pandas 1.0.5

Comment: I noticed that if i delete print(df) and run the code, the dataframe is printed anyway.

Comment: If i run the code on Jupiter or Colab all seems to work well !